# Weight paint painting on both sides?

Tags: weight-painting

I’m doing the donut tutorial of Blender Guru and I’m on the sprinkles bit.

When I pull out the weight paint to make sure it doesn't show sprinkles on the bottom of the icing, the weight paint paints on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that you don't paint through, make sure that you've activated one of these brush options (I still don't understand how it works though):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So i thought to add this because i did the above and was still getting the weight paint on both sides. I found that i hadn't applied the modifiers to the shape as a result the mesh was still having a single side.